# Itext Sharp Report is not able to generate the Report For more than 37000 records

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, itext

I have tried to build the pdf For more than 37000 records but I am getting `system out of memory` exception and I have also tried after deploying the same in `Staging server` but getting `time out` ,I also increased the time out in the Web.config but not able to produce the report.Can Anyone help on this.

**Controller.**

**[HttpPost]**

```
public async Task<FileContentResult> GeneralReport(SearchCriteria model)
    {
        return File(await Task.Run(() => _reportService.CreateReports(model)), "application/pdf", "General Ledger.PDF");
    }
```

**Method.**

```
public byte[] CreateGeneralLedgerReports(GLReportSearchCriteria reportcriteria)
        {
            byte[] CoreData = this.GenerateLedgerCorePDF(reportcriteria);
            List<PdfReader> pdfcollection = new List<PdfReader>();
            pdfcollection.Add(new PdfReader(CoreData));
            byte[] combineoutput = this.MergLedgerDocuments(pdfcollection, reportcriteria);
            return combineoutput;
        }



private byte[] GenerateLedgerCorePDF(GLReportSearchCriteria reportcriteria)
        {
            Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(842f, 595f), 25, 25, 60, 25);
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
            writer.CloseStream = false;        
            document.Open();
            Chapter ChapterforSection = new Chapter(new Paragraph("", _titleFont), i);
            ChapterforSection.NumberDepth = 0;
            Paragraph pp = new Paragraph("", _ColorFont);
            pp.Add(this.AddGenerateLedgerSection(reportcriteria));
            ChapterforSection.AddSection(pp, 0);
            document.Add(ChapterforSection);
            document.Close();
            return output.ToArray();
        }


private PdfPTable AddGenerateLedgerSection(GLReportSearchCriteria reportcriteria)
        {
            int? a = reportcriteria.Period + reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd;

            List<GLGeneralLedgerReport> result = (from o in _repo.GLAccounts
                                                  join b in _repo.GLAccountTotals
                                                  on o.AccountID equals b.AccountID
                                                  where (o.Corporation.Equals(reportcriteria.Corporation)
                                                  && b.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear
                                               && (b.Period >= reportcriteria.Period && b.Period <= a))
                                                  select new GLGeneralLedgerReport
                                                  {
                                                      AccountNumber = o.AccountNumber,
                                                      AccountDescription = o.AccountDescription,
                                                      AccountID = o.AccountID,
                                                      YTDBalance = o.YTDBalance,
                                                      ClassCode = o.ClassCode,
                                                      NormalBalance = o.NormalBalance
                                                  }).AsNoTracking().ToList();

            List<Guid?> AccountiDs = result.Select(b => b.AccountID).ToList();
            // var result2 = _financeService.GetGeneralLedgerIDDetails(item.AccountID).AsNoTracking().ToList();
            var result2 = _repo.GLAccountJournals.Where(b => AccountiDs.Contains(b.AccountID)).ToList();
            //from r in _repo.GLAccountTotals where r.AccountID == AccountId && r.Period == BalanceFrwd select r;
            //var result3 = _financeService.GetGeneralLedgerTotalDetails(item.AccountID, reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd).AsNoTracking().ToList();
            var result3 = _repo.GLAccountTotals.Where(b => AccountiDs.Contains(b.AccountID) && b.Period == reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd).ToList(); ;
            //var result3 = _financeService.GetGeneralLedgerTotalDetails(item.AccountID, reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd).AsNoTracking().ToList();

            PdfPTable maintable = ReportStyleHelper.GetTable(1);
            PdfPTable headertable = ReportStyleHelper.GetTable(1);

            headertable.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetChapterHeader(reportcriteria.Corporation, 7));
            headertable.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetChapterHeader("General Ledger Report", 7));
            headertable.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetChapterHeader("From " + ReportStyleHelper.PeriodToDate(reportcriteria.Period, reportcriteria.FiscalYear), 7));
            headertable.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetChapterHeader("To " + ReportStyleHelper.PeriodToDate(Convert.ToInt32(a), reportcriteria.FiscalYear), 7));
            maintable.AddCell(headertable);

            PdfPTable table = ReportStyleHelper.GetTable(8, new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f });
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Account", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(item.AccountNumber));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(item.AccountDescription));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Balance frw ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(Convert.ToString(a - reportcriteria.Period)));

                if (result.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var datas in result.Where(u => u.Period == reportcriteria.Period))
                    {
                        table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(Convert.ToDecimal(datas.YTDBalance).ToString("#,##0.00")));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(1));
                }
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(3));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetParagraphSeparater(8));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Period", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Journal Id", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("System", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Source Description", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Posting Date", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Debit", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Credit", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Balance", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                //table5.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetParagraphSeparater(8));



                //var data = result2.Where(u => u.Period == Convert.ToString(reportcriteria.Period)).ToList();
                foreach (var item2 in result2)
                {
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText((reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd).ToString()));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item2.JournalID.ToString()));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item2.System));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item2.SourceDescription));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item2.PostDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(Convert.ToDecimal(item2.DebitAmount).ToString("#,##0.00")));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(Convert.ToDecimal(item2.CreditAmount).ToString("#,##0.00")));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(1));

                }


                var data3 = result3.Where(u => u.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear && (u.Period >= reportcriteria.Period && u.Period <= a)).ToList();
                foreach (var item3 in data3)
                {
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(4));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Net change", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(Convert.ToDecimal(item3.NetChange).ToString("#,##0.00")));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Ending balance", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(Convert.ToDecimal(item3.YTDBalance).ToString("#,##0.00")));
                }
                maintable.AddCell(table);
            }

            PdfPTable tablelast = ReportStyleHelper.GetTable(3, new float[] { 1f, 1f, 1f });
            var aggregateResult = result.GroupBy(x => x.ClassCode).Select(
                 x => new
                 {
                     ClassCode = x.Key,
                     NormalBalance = x.Sum(y => Convert.ToDecimal(y.NormalBalance)),
                     YTDBalance = x.Sum(y => y.YTDBalance),
                 }
                 );
            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(1));
            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Current"));
            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Year to Date "));
            foreach (var aggregate in aggregateResult)
            {

                tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetDetailSectionLabel("Totals By " + aggregate.ClassCode, 1));
                tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(Convert.ToDecimal(aggregate.NormalBalance).ToString("#,##0.00")));
                tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(Convert.ToDecimal(aggregate.YTDBalance).ToString("#,##0.00")));
                // tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetParagraphSeparater(7));
            }
            maintable.AddCell(tablelast);
            return maintable;
        }
```

Comment: You are creating the PDF in memory (in a `MemoryStream`) and then create a copy of the stream contents in memory (in `output.ToArray()`), so for a short time you even keep two copies of the PDF in memory. This pattern obviously only makes sense for relatively small PDFs, not larger than a few MB, in particular on a server. If you want to be able to create very large reports, be more conservative about your memory resources.

Comment: Furthermore, you create a giant `PdfPTable maintable` in `AddGenerateLedgerSection` and return it as result; this table contains essentially all the information of the main part. This pattern also makes only sense for small amounts of data, tables not longer than a very few pages. For *more than 37000 records* this architecture is a no-go because this `PdfPTable` is built in memory and iText has no chance to serialize the data early. Thus, even if you acted on my previous comment, this architecture here would still result in huge memory usage.

Comment: I agreed with your points,but what is the solution of this problem??I mean if if this architecture is not right for large amount of data then what is the alternate solution for this problem using ITextsharp only.

Comment: iText has support for adding tables little by little to a document. Look at e.g. [this example](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/tables-itext5/large-tables) from the iText web page - it is written in Java but is easy to port to C#.

Comment: Thanks For your help,Actually I implemented the similar logic ,I have created the Pdftable and added the same table in paragraph for each accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution ,I have created the PDFTable and added them in paragraph for each account like this

```
 private byte[] GenerateLedgerCorePDF(GLReportSearchCriteria reportcriteria)
    {
        Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(842f, 595f), 25, 25, 60, 25);/*new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, NewHeaderlogoHeight + 20f, 25);*/
        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
        writer.CloseStream = false;
        document.Open();
        Chapter ChapterforSection = new Chapter(new Paragraph("", _titleFont), i);
        ChapterforSection.NumberDepth = 0;
        Paragraph pp = new Paragraph("", _ColorFont);
        List<GLGeneralLedgerReport> result = null;
        if (reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd < reportcriteria.Period)
        {
            result = (from o in _repo.GLAccounts
                      join b in _repo.GLAccountTotals
                      on o.AccountID equals b.AccountID
                      where (o.Corporation.Equals(reportcriteria.Corporation)
                      && b.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear
                   && (b.Period > reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd && b.Period <= reportcriteria.Period))
                      select new GLGeneralLedgerReport
                      {
                          AccountNumber = o.AccountNumber,
                          AccountType = o.AccountType,
                          AccountDescription = o.AccountDescription,
                          AccountID = o.AccountID,
                          YTDBalance = b.YTDBalance,
                          ClassCode = o.ClassCode,
                          NormalBalance = o.NormalBalance,
                          NetChange = b.NetChange
                      }).OrderBy(b => b.AccountNumber).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            result = (from o in _repo.GLAccounts
                      join b in _repo.GLAccountTotals
                      on o.AccountID equals b.AccountID
                      where (o.Corporation.Equals(reportcriteria.Corporation)
                      && b.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear
                   && (b.Period == reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd))
                      select new GLGeneralLedgerReport
                      {
                          AccountNumber = o.AccountNumber,
                          AccountType = o.AccountType,
                          AccountDescription = o.AccountDescription,
                          AccountID = o.AccountID,
                          YTDBalance = b.YTDBalance,
                          ClassCode = o.ClassCode,
                          NormalBalance = o.NormalBalance,
                          NetChange = b.NetChange
                      }).OrderBy(b => b.AccountNumber).ToList();


        }

        List<GLGeneralLedgerReport> resultOne = (from o in _repo.GLAccounts
                                                 join b in _repo.GLAccountTotals
                                                 on o.AccountID equals b.AccountID
                                                 where (o.Corporation.Equals(reportcriteria.Corporation)
                                                 && b.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear
                                              && (b.Period == reportcriteria.Period))
                                                 select new GLGeneralLedgerReport
                                                 {
                                                     AccountNumber = o.AccountNumber,
                                                     AccountType = o.AccountType,
                                                     AccountDescription = o.AccountDescription,
                                                     AccountID = o.AccountID,
                                                     YTDBalance = b.YTDBalance,
                                                     ClassCode = o.ClassCode,
                                                     NormalBalance = o.NormalBalance,
                                                     NetChange = b.NetChange
                                                 }).OrderBy(b => b.AccountNumber).ToList();

        List<Guid?> AccountiDs = result.Select(s => s.AccountID).Distinct().ToList();
        PdfPTable headertable = ReportStyleHelper.GetTable(1);

        headertable.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetChapterHeader(reportcriteria.Corporation, 7));
        headertable.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetChapterHeader("General Ledger Report", 7));
        headertable.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetChapterHeader("From 01/" + reportcriteria.FiscalYear + " To " + reportcriteria.Period + "/" + reportcriteria.FiscalYear, 7));

        pp.Add(headertable);
        foreach (Guid AccountiD in AccountiDs)
        {
            pp.Add(this.AddGenerateLedgerSection(AccountiD, reportcriteria));
        }

        PdfPTable tablelast = ReportStyleHelper.GetTable(3, new float[] { 2f, 1f, 1f });
        var aggregateResult = resultOne.GroupBy(x => x.AccountType).Select(
             x => new
             {
                 AccountType = x.Key,
                 NetChange = x.Sum(y => Convert.ToDecimal(y.NetChange)),
                 YTDBalance = x.Sum(y => y.YTDBalance),
             }
             ).ToList();
        var AELaggregateResult = aggregateResult.Where(a => a.AccountType == "Assets" || a.AccountType == "Equity" || a.AccountType == "Liabilities").ToList();
        var NOTAELaggregateResult = aggregateResult.Except(AELaggregateResult).ToList();

        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Totals"));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Current"));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Year to Date "));

        foreach (var aggregate in AELaggregateResult)
        {

            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Totals By " + aggregate.AccountType, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(aggregate.NetChange))));
            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(aggregate.YTDBalance))));
        }
        var AELprofitlossNetchange = aggregateResult.Where(a => a.AccountType == "Assets" || a.AccountType == "Equity" || a.AccountType == "Liabilities").Sum(a => a.NetChange);
        var AELprofitlossYTDBal = aggregateResult.Where(a => a.AccountType == "Assets" || a.AccountType == "Equity" || a.AccountType == "Liabilities").Sum(a => a.YTDBalance);
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(3));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Profit or Loss"));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(AELprofitlossNetchange))));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(AELprofitlossYTDBal))));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(3));
        foreach (var aggregate in NOTAELaggregateResult)
        {

            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Totals By " + aggregate.AccountType, PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(aggregate.NetChange))));
            tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(aggregate.YTDBalance))));
        }
        var NotAELprofitlossNetchange = NOTAELaggregateResult.Sum(a => a.NetChange);
        var NotAELprofitlossYTDBal = NOTAELaggregateResult.Sum(a => a.YTDBalance);
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(3));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Profit or Loss"));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(NotAELprofitlossNetchange))));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(NotAELprofitlossYTDBal))));
        tablelast.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(3));
        pp.Add(tablelast);
        ChapterforSection.AddSection(pp, 0);
        document.Add(ChapterforSection);
        document.Close();
        return output.ToArray();
    }

 private PdfPTable AddGenerateLedgerSection(Guid AccountiD, GLReportSearchCriteria reportcriteria)
    {
        GLAccount result = _repo.GLAccounts.Where(b => b.AccountID == AccountiD).FirstOrDefault();
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(reportcriteria.FiscalYear);
        var resultGLAccountTotals = _repo.GLAccountTotals.Where(b => b.AccountID == AccountiD).ToList();
        decimal? YTDBalance = resultGLAccountTotals.Where(b => b.Period == reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd && b.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear).Select(x => x.YTDBalance).FirstOrDefault();


        PdfPTable table = ReportStyleHelper.GetTable(8, new float[] { 1f, 1f, 2.5f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f, 1f });
        table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Account", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(result.AccountNumber));
        table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(result.AccountDescription));
        table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Balance frw ", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
        table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(Convert.ToString(reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd)));
        table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(YTDBalance == null ? 0 : YTDBalance)), PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT, 3));


        var resultGLAccountJournals = _repo.GLAccountJournals.Where(b => b.AccountID == AccountiD).OrderBy(b => b.JournalID).ToList();
        var filteredGLAccountJournals = resultGLAccountJournals.Where(a => a.PeriodReport > reportcriteria.BalanceFrwd && a.PeriodReport <= reportcriteria.Period && a.YearReport == year).ToList();
        var periodlist = filteredGLAccountJournals.Select(a => a.PeriodReport).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
        decimal? NetChange = 0;
        decimal? LastYTDBalance = 0;
        if (filteredGLAccountJournals.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item1 in periodlist)
            {
                NetChange = resultGLAccountTotals.Where(b => b.Period == item1 && b.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear).Select(x => x.NetChange).FirstOrDefault();
                LastYTDBalance = resultGLAccountTotals.Where(b => b.Period == item1 && b.Year == reportcriteria.FiscalYear).Select(x => x.YTDBalance).FirstOrDefault();

                var filteredGLAccountJournals2 = filteredGLAccountJournals.Where(b => b.PeriodReport == item1).ToList();
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetParagraphSeparater(8));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Period", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Journal Id", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("System", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Source Description", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Posting Date", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Debit", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Credit", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Balance", PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT));

                foreach (var item in filteredGLAccountJournals2)
                {
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText((item.PeriodReport).ToString()));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item.JournalID.ToString()));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item.SourceSystem));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item.SourceDescription));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(item.PostDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(item.DebitAmount))));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(item.CreditAmount))));
                    table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(1));

                }
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(6));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Net change", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDecimal(NetChange == null ? 0 : NetChange)))));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(6));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Ending balance", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDecimal(LastYTDBalance == null ? 0 : LastYTDBalance)))));
                table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetParagraphSeparater(8));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(6));
            table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Net change", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDecimal(NetChange == null ? 0 : NetChange)))));
            table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetEmptyCell(6));
            table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionLabel("Ending balance", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
            table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetSectionText(string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToDecimal(Convert.ToDecimal(LastYTDBalance == null ? 0 : LastYTDBalance)))));
            table.AddCell(ReportStyleHelper.GetParagraphSeparater(8));
        }
        return table;
    }
```